# SQL Query in JavaSpring Returning Null

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to do a simple SQL call through Java Spring. The database has data but on the call is returning a list of null values.

What's interesting is that when I select a particular row, it returns the correct value. (See below)

BasicAccountAuditRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface BasicAccountAuditRepository extends CrudRepository<BasicAccountAudit, BasicAccountAuditPK> {

    List<BasicAccountAudit> findAll();

//THIS RETURNS NULL
    @Query("SELECT b FROM BasicAccountAudit as b WHERE id.accountRef  = :accountRef ")  
    List<BasicAccountAudit> findByAccountRef(@Param("accountRef") String accountRef);

//This returns the correct values for dcConnName
    @Query("SELECT id.dcConnName FROM BasicAccountAudit WHERE id.accountRef  = :accountRef ")  
    List<BasicAccountAudit> findByAccountRef(@Param("accountRef") String accountRef);

}
```

I'm using an embedded ID for the model class.
BasicAccountAudit.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_Account_History", schema="dbo")

public class BasicAccountAudit implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private BasicAccountAuditPK id;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(insertable = true, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date enteredDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(insertable = true, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;


}
```

Here is the Primary Key Class: 
BasicAccountAuditPK.java

```
package org.fusion.restful.basicaccount.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class BasicAccountAuditPK implements Serializable {

    private String accountRef;
    private String client;
    private String dcEligible;
    private String shortCode;
    private String loadCps;
    private String stpFlag;
    private String accountType;
    private String clearingFirm;
    private String exchange;
    private String dcConnName;
    private String status; 
    private String enteredBy;

 //getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: Set logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug and post the generated SQL statements

Comment: Hi Simon! Where do i set that? Sorry I'm very new to this

Comment: In the application.properties file

Comment: Why do you use queries while you can do exactly the same thing with Data JPA method naming? Like `List<BasicAccountAudit> findAllByAccountRef(String accountRef);` ?

Comment: @DmytroGrynets i tried using that method before but accountRef is part of the id class and the above query returns an error becuase accountRef is not part of BasicAccountAudit (its part of BasicAccountAuditPK)

Comment: @MarkJ Perhaps you should try something like `List<BasicAccountAudit> findAllById_AccountRef(String accountRef);` ? Not sure if it will work though

Comment: @DmytroGrynets that did not work either :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to be consistent with the alias usage.
In your first query you have forgotten the alias in your `where` clause:

```
"SELECT b FROM BasicAccountAudit as b WHERE id.accountRef  = :accountRef "
```

should be

```
SELECT b FROM BasicAccountAudit as b WHERE b.id.accountRef  = :accountRef "
```

In your second query you don't declare alias therefore by default it is looking up the id under your object.

Comment: Hello, I tried the query you posted and am facing the same issue. Its returning a list of null values